# starting nginx - command not found

Tags: ubuntu, opensuse, command, nginx

I can't start nginx for some reason.

The server is OpenSUSE; I have done the following:

1. Installed http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.0.5.tar.gz
2. extracted the folder
3. run ./configure
4. make
5. make install

The nginx have been extracted to /usr/local/nginx/sbin where I can see the nginx.
But when I try to run any commands it says "command not found".

When running ./configure it says;

```
Configuration summary
  + using system PCRE library
  + OpenSSL library is not used
  + using system zlib library

  nginx path prefix: "/usr/local/nginx"
  nginx binary file: "/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx"
  nginx modules path: "/usr/local/nginx/modules"
  nginx configuration prefix: "/usr/local/nginx/conf"
  nginx configuration file: "/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"
  nginx pid file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid"
  nginx error log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log"
  nginx http access log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log"
  nginx http client request body temporary files: "client_body_temp"
  nginx http proxy temporary files: "proxy_temp"
  nginx http fastcgi temporary files: "fastcgi_temp"
  nginx http uwsgi temporary files: "uwsgi_temp"
  nginx http scgi temporary files: "scgi_temp"
```

which I guess is fine, even though in the log it says some stuff not found, but I don't think this is essential?

When running make:

```
-ldl -lpthread -lcrypt -lpcre -lz \
-Wl,-E
sed -e "s|%%PREFIX%%|/usr/local/nginx|" \
    -e "s|%%PID_PATH%%|/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid|" \
    -e "s|%%CONF_PATH%%|/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf|" \
    -e "s|%%ERROR_LOG_PATH%%|/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log|" \
    < man/nginx.8 > objs/nginx.8
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/nginx/nginx-1.12.2'

when running echo $PATH  it says;

    /usr/sbin/:/usr/sbin/:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

I can see the nginx, though, in sbin?

Comment: which system are you using?

Comment: I am using opensuse

Comment: try systemctl start nginx

Comment: I did, it said Job for nginx.service failed. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xn" for details.

Comment: output of journal ctl plz

Comment: dec 08 18:30:33 server nginx[16936]: nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("www-data") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Comment: -- The result is failed.
dec 08 18:30:33 server nginx[16936]: nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("www-data") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
dec 08 18:30:33 server nginx[16936]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
dec 08 18:30:33 server systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit nginx.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.

Comment: Seems: The error message basically means that the user www-data which I  defined in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf doesn’t exists in /etc/passwd.

Comment: I am kinda new to this, what is this fix for this? and shouldn't it do the setup automatically when running configure, make and make install?

Comment: paste the outpout of cat /etc/password and your nginx.conf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69930/discussion-between-vfbsilva-and-strawhat).

Answer (score 3):

Could you verify the path the nginx executable is located at? It looks like two different paths:

> /usr/local/sbin/ (path)
>
> /usr/local/nginx/sbin/ (nginx executable)

Just because they both have `/usr/local/` and `/sbin/` in them doesn't make them the same, `/usr/local/sbin/` is a different path than `/usr/local/nginx/`. Based on the paths you provided, `/usr/local/sbin/` is being checked, but not `/usr/local/nginx/sbin`. You would want/need to executable moved, or add `/usr/local/nginx/sbin` to your path.

Comment: How do I add the path?

Comment: If you just want to add it to *your* path, see this article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638025/5670331 As that answer mentions, you might be better off just creating a symlink as a more global/permanent solution.